# Hibernate SQLQuery neglecting aliasname

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When i try to execute the following query in mysql , it works perfectly. But when we try it via Hibernate(3.2) ,hibernate is not differentiating `m.NAME` and `o.NAME`. It is returning the same result for both as `m.NAME`.

`SELECT m.NAME, m.SCREENNAME, rm.ADDRESS, o.NAME FROM remoteunit rm LEFT JOIN mo m ON rm.MOID = m.ID JOIN overallcustomfields ocf ON m.ID = ocf.MOID LEFT JOIN organization o ON ocf.ORGID = o.ID WHERE m.DOMAINID = 2`

Iam using the following code

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
query.setLong("customId", customId);
remoteUnitList = (ArrayList<Object[]>)query.list();
transaction.commit();
```

**Note:** Forced to use `SQLQuery` in `Hibernate` since the columns are dynamically populated and more constraints.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT m.NAME as m_name, o.NAME as o_name...`. I faced the same problem and it went of with this change.

Comment: Thanks ambrish, its working but that looks dirty for me. Iam creating these query dynamically and its now long like a page. Do we have any other option. Please post an answer your suggestion works for me, i will accept that.

Comment: I know it looks dirty, but when you are writing your own `SQL` then better use your own aliasing (my personal experience).

Comment: You mentioned columns are dynamically populated. Can you try the Criteria API for dynamically creating your query ?

Comment: I have tried that, not working, but i got the workaround as @Ambrish posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `SELECT m.NAME as m_name, o.NAME as o_name...`. I faced the same problem and it went of with this change.